# Android- start a dialog when application on background

Tags: android, qt, qtandroidextras

I have an application which has call dialog. I'm trying to show call dialog on lock screen. it has worked when application was not on background, actually it didn't work when application was open and lock screen was active.

 Here is my code:

```
    public class CustomMainActivity extends QtActivity implements SensorEventListener
    {

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (getCallId() != 0)
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        else
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    .
    .
    .
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (getCallId() != 0)
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        else
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    .
    .
    .
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these flags inside `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: I've added this line on onCreate. if application is open and goes to sleep it wont show call dialog. in another cases , it's working.

Comment: your dialog is in different activity ? I mean how you are showing your dialog ?

Comment: my dialog on Qt, I check callstate -       if (getCallId() != 0) - if call receive, I just want to show call dialog

Comment: i mean to say you must need to start a separate activity(including those flags inside onCreate) to show the dialog.